# No such a column key

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to add to the DB some keywords from a text file.

After having created the database and table and connected to it, I can not insert the data as I get an error no such a column.

Here is what I am trying:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('AKeywords.db')
c = conn.cursor()
# Table structure here below as created.
# c.execute("CREATE TABLE Keywords(key text, initials text, words integer, special text, digit text)")

with open('C:/Users/CobraCommander/Desktop/keys.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as key_text_file:
for key in key_text_file:
    key = key.strip()
    words = key.count(' ') + 1
    initials = key[:2]
    special = hasSpecial(key)  # Function that looks for special char
    digit = hasDigits(key)     # Function that looks for digits
    print('Keyword:',key,'Words No:',words,'Initials:',initials,'Special:',special,'Digits:',digit)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Keywords VALUES (key, initials, words, special, digit)")
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This is the error that I get:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: key

How do I insert these values from the text file into the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated this line

```
 c.execute("INSERT INTO Keywords VALUES (key, initials, words, special, digit)")
```

to

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Keywords VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (key,words, initials,special,digit));
```

Comment: Hi @metal , it gives me the same error, however with [key] instead of key.

Comment: Hi @metal, can you kindly update the answer for python user like this: c.execute("INSERT INTO Keywords VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (key,words, initials,special,digit))  so I can assign you the answer? Thanks